# Can't get the Make to work without getting a Seg Fault error

Tags: c, makefile

Sorry for the newbie question incoming.

My program is the classic labyrinth solver program. The functions and everything work beautifully when on the same file. However, for cleaner use, I'm now trying to separate them and use the Make to render them together.

Unfortunately, when I do this, I get a Segmentation Fault error. I can't seem to find the bug, so I'm asking for help.

These are the main file and function file.

Thanks,
Gerald

Main file:

```
/*Librerías del sistema*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*Librerías específicas del programa*/
#include "laberinto1.h"

/*Defines del programa*/

#define ERR_NUM_PARAM "Numero incorrecto de parametros.\n"
#define ERR_PARAM "El punto (%d, %d) no pertenece al laberinto.\n"
#define ERR_SALIDA "No existe salida desde el punto (%d, %d).\n"
#define ERR_OBSTACULO "El punto (%d, %d) es un obstaculo.\n"


int encuentraRuta (int posv, int posh, char lab[TAMV][TAMH]);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    /* Definición de base y altura */

    int altura = atoi(argv[1]);
    int base = atoi(argv[2]);

    /* Defino la tabla */
    char laberinto[TAMV][TAMH] = {LABERINTO};


    /* Comprobaciones de números introducidos */

    if (argc != 3)
        printf(ERR_NUM_PARAM);

    else if (altura >= TAMV || base >= TAMH)
        printf(ERR_PARAM, altura, base);

    else if (laberinto[altura][base] == '#')
        printf(ERR_OBSTACULO, altura, base);

    else {

        encuentraRuta (altura, base, laberinto);

        /* Ints */

        int v;
        int h;

        /* Imprimo el laberinto */

        for (v = 0; v < TAMV; v++){

            for (h =0; h < TAMH; h++)
                printf("%c", laberinto[v][h]);

            printf ("\n");

        }

        return 0;

    }
}
```

Function file:

```
/* Defines e includes*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "encruta1.h"
#include "laberinto1.h"

int encuentraRuta (int posv, int posh, char lab[TAMV][TAMH]) {

    /* Variable de control que le indicará a las recursivas si la anterior ha encontrado un hueco sin obstáculo */
    int resuelto = NO;

    /*Si está en el borde, será el fin de la función ya que será la solución*/
    if ((posh == 0) || (posv == 0) || posh == (TAMH - 1) || posv == (TAMV - 1))
        resuelto = SI;

    /* Si no está en el borde, comenzamos las recursivas a comprobar todos los huecos pegados a el actual */
    else {

        lab[posv][posh] = 'o'; /* Se marcan los huecos "leidos" */

        if (lab[posv][posh + 1] == '.')
            resuelto = encuentraRuta(posv, posh + 1, lab);

        if ((lab[posv][posh - 1] == '.') && (resuelto == NO))
            resuelto = encuentraRuta(posv, posh - 1, lab);

        if ((lab[posv + 1][posh] == '.') && (resuelto == NO))
            resuelto = encuentraRuta(posv + 1, posh, lab);

        if ((lab[posv - 1][posh] == '.') && (resuelto == NO))
            resuelto = encuentraRuta(posv - 1, posh, lab);
    }

    /* Se marcan las soluciones correctas con * */
    if (resuelto == SI )
        lab[posv][posh] = '*';

    return resuelto;
}
```

Makefile file:

```
laberinto1: laberinto1.o encruta1.o
    gcc -o laberinto1 laberinto1.o encruta1.o

laberinto1.o: laberinto1.c laberinto1.h
    gcc -W -Wall -c laberinto1.c

encruta1.o: encruta1.c encruta1.h
    gcc -W -Wall -c encruta1.c

borra:
    rm *.o
```

Cheers!

Comment: Ow, I expected the negative votes, hard to take, but at least an answer. I have tried running the gdb (lldb now for me) and get a very strange error. Read everywhere around, but can't get to the error...

Comment: This code is not complete. It would be very helpful if you gave us a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. The function was declared twice, both in the heather of the function file, and in the Main file.

Cheers!